# NullPointerException in JavaFX initialize in TableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I have this controller class for showing a database query in a TableView, but i am having error of NullPointerException with the "setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory"

```
package aplicativo;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class Controle implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    private TextField txtCampo,txtCampo2;
    @FXML
    private Button btAdicionar,btConsultar;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Pessoa> tabValues;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Pessoa, Integer> tbcCod;
    private TableColumn<Pessoa, String>tbcNome;
    ObservableList<Pessoa> List = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @FXML
    private void btAdd(){
        insertBD a = new insertBD(txtCampo.getText());
        consultaBD b = new consultaBD();
        List = b.consultaTudo();
        tabValues.setItems(List);
        txtCampo.clear();
    }
    @FXML

    private void btCons(){
        String tx = txtCampo2.getText();
        if(tx.isEmpty()){

        }else{
        consultaBD a = new consultaBD();
        a.consultaParecido(tx, "nome");
        txtCampo2.clear();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tbcCod.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Pessoa, Integer>("cod"));
        tbcNome.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Pessoa, String>("nome"));
        tabValues.setItems(List);
        tabValues.getColumns().addAll(tbcCod,tbcNome);
    }
}
```

The NullPointerExcepetion:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$50/1645995473.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/lucas/workspace/BDFX/bin/aplicativo/Tela.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at aplicativo.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/1031257736.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/186276003.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/1529876784.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/237061348.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at aplicativo.Controle.initialize(Controle.java:52)
    ... 23 more
Exception running application aplicativo.Main
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the instance fields in your controller is lacking an `@FXML` annotation.  Since the field is private, the FXML loader is unable to inject the control reference into the field during loading.  Here are your instance field declarations:

```
@FXML
private TextField txtCampo,txtCampo2;

@FXML
private Button btAdicionar,btConsultar;

@FXML
private TableView<Pessoa> tabValues;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Pessoa, Integer> tbcCod;

private TableColumn<Pessoa, String>tbcNome;
```

Notice that the last field, tbcNome, is not annotated.  As a result, when your initialize method is called, the `tbcNome` field contains a `null` reference, resulting in the exception.

To fix your problem, all you may need to do is add the `@FXML` annotation to the instance field declaration for `tbcNome`.

You may have encouraged this error by adopting the habit of listing more than one variable in your type declarations, eg. `private Button btAdicionar, btConsultar;`.  In my opinion, this is a bad habit that can encourage errors like this to happen.  I would suggest that you try to adopt the coding style in which each instance field has its own type declaration statement.